Dot product under parallel transport
I was wondering about simple justification that parallel transport preserves dot product value. I came up with an idea like that:
$u^i$ - 1st vector in covariant basis
$v_i$ - 2nd vector in contravariant basis
Dot product is straight forward then:
$$\vec u\cdot\vec v=u^iv_i$$
Parallel transport requires that:
$$\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial\xi^j}=-{\Gamma^i}_{jl}u^l$$
$$\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial\xi^k}={\Gamma^m}_{ik}v_m$$
Fields can be expanded to 1st order:
$$u^i(\xi^1+\Delta x^1,\xi^2+\Delta x^2,...)\approx u^i+\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial\xi^j}\Delta x^j=u^i-{\Gamma^i}_{jl}u^l\Delta x^j$$
$$v_i(\xi^1+\Delta x^1,\xi^2+\Delta x^2,...)\approx v_i+\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial\xi^k}\Delta x^k=v_i+{\Gamma^m}_{ik}v_m\Delta x^k$$
Then, dot product in vicinity of original point would be:
$$(u^i-{\Gamma^i}_{jl}u^l\Delta x^j)(v_i+{\Gamma^m}_{ik}v_m\Delta x^k)=u^iv_i-{\Gamma^i}_{jl}u^lv_i\Delta x^j+{\Gamma^m}_{ik}u^iv_m\Delta x^k-{\Gamma^i}_{jl}{\Gamma^m}_{ik}u^lv_m\Delta x^j\Delta x^k=\\=u^iv_i-{\Gamma^i}_{jl}u^lv_i\Delta x^j+{\Gamma^i}_{lj}u^lv_i\Delta x^j-{\Gamma^i}_{jl}{\Gamma^m}_{ik}u^lv_m\Delta x^j\Delta x^k=u^iv_i-{\Gamma^i}_{jl}{\Gamma^m}_{ik}u^lv_m\Delta x^j\Delta x^k$$
This leaves 2nd order term. Can we assume that it is negligible and this concludes justification?

Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/832933/2451

I think there are three parts to answer

First of all, if $u$ is a vector and $v$ is a covector, then if they are both parallel transported along the same curve $\gamma$, then the value of $v(u)$ will be constant on $\gamma$. No need for approximations in this case. This does not have to hold if $u$ and $v$ are vectors parallel transported along $\gamma$ and that inner product is calculated using metric tensor.
Secondly, you cannot assume that relation
$$ \frac{\partial u^i}{\partial \xi^j} = - \Gamma^i_{jk} u^k$$
holds for all indices. This would mean that $u$ is covariantly constant which is highly constraining – for example, 2 dimensional curved manifold with Levi-Civita connection does not admit any covariantly constant vector fields (different than zero vector field).
Thirdly, I think you have your indices mixed. If you define
$$\nabla_{\partial_i} \partial_j =  \Gamma^k_{ij} \partial_k$$
then
$$\nabla_{\partial_i} dx^j = - \Gamma^j_{ik} dx^k$$
and because of that $\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial \xi^k} = \Gamma^m_{ki} v_m$ instead of your $\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial \xi^k} = \Gamma^m_{ik} v_m$. This means that you should get a first order in $\Gamma$ element that is proportional to difference $\Gamma^i_{jk} - \Gamma^i_{kj}$ that won't necessarily vanish unless connection is torsion-free.

